# .Net Core - Culture in Razor View

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get the current culture in .Net Core 2 from the Razor page.
Basically I have a site which handles various languages. At the top of the page I set the page title as such...

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutNotAuthorised.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = ApplicationName.Resources.Authentication_Login.Resources.PageTitle.Productise("http://localhost");
}
```

As you can see I have an extension method called 'Productise' and this takes the string from the resources (which contains a placeholder) and basically replaces it with the product name. The issue I'm having is that I created filter which sets the current Thread's culture based upon either a cookie or the browser settings (which ever is present). This works fine, I can in the immediate window check this within the controller.

The issue I am facing is that when the controller returns the view and I then step through the view's razor code (and perform the same check in the immediate window) it shows that that current thread's culture is blank. When the razor page calls the extension method, at that point the culture is still blank.

Is this meant to happen or is this a bug? This is a migration from a none core application.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1? While I don't know why this is failing for you at the moment, I'd probably try to follow the "happy path" of the expected approach for i18n rather than creating an alternative approach.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the new approach but I'm looking to do multiple things not covered in the new approach (they weren't totally covered in the old approach either) so I created my own which is DB driven (not resource files) and is dynamic i.e Company A can change 'Record Id' to be 'Case Id' in their account where Company B may want it to stay as 'Record Id'...and then each of them could have multiple translations etc.

Comment: That just sounds like it's a matter of implementing IViewLocalizer yourself though - the rest of the middleware could stay the same.